# Unexpected exiting when simulate in Modelsim

Tags: modelsim

I am using Modelsim 10.4a to simulate my verilog code, and I have tb file to test my another .v file. Both of files are compiled successfully, but when I tried to run -all to see wave, it give me a message:

Modelsim is exiting with code 7. check the transcript file for more information on the fatal error.

Are there any clue for me to know what probably cause this. I didn't see any transcript in my project file and solution in google. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The user manual list the error codes in the Appendix. This is file not found.

You can find the location of the transcript file by doing

**Tools > Edit Preferences > By Name > Main > file**

Comment: I only see it has a block let me change name of transcript file, I didn't see its location. I also check my project file, it also not exist.

Comment: And do you know how to show the meaning of  code 7 in modelsim command line? Because I didn't find answer in google. Thanks!